# Installing yii2 via composer and it keeps prompting for a password

Tags: composer-php, yii2

I am just following instructions from the yii website and don't really understand composer. I followed the instructions from here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

The authentication seems to be working but then it prompts me for the username/password again and again.

Anyone got some things I can check to see why it keeps prompting?

```
[root@dndbox html]# composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-basic (dev-master b528289495bf9721d2b8c628d69caad42e45b0ce)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-basic (dev-master master)
    Downloading: connection...
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/zipball/b528289495bf9721d2b8c628d69caad42e45b0ce, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /root/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: *.com
Password: 
An existing OAuth token for Composer is present and will be reused

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/authorizations, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /root/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: *.com
Password: 
An existing OAuth token for Composer is present and will be reused

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/authorizations, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /root/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username:
```

==================================== EDIT 1 =====================================

If I visit the URL provided I get a error message in the json,  https://api.github.com/authorizations

```
{
  "message": "API rate limit exceeded for xxx.xxx.xxx.26. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It may helps you more. Follow the steps:

1. Create/Sign in into github account.
2. Go to **Profile>>Settings>>Personal access tokens** (OR) click on this https://github.com/settings/tokens.
3. Click on **Generate new token**
4. Select the appropriate scopes and click **Generate token**.
5. Copy the the token Key and past it in composer when the composer want you the Token(like: Token (Hidden):)

Now it will enter into the installation process.

Good Luck...

Answer (score 5):

see this answer on the forum

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60340-issue-while-installing-yii-2/page__view__findpost__p__269389

it helped me

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a Github account.
2. Go to https://github.com/s...gs/applications and delete your previous token generated during the installation of yii2
3. Create a new token.
4. Run this: composer config -g github-oauth.github.com
5. Retry again with the yii2 installation